# node-gyp rebuild fails for optional dependency weak on mac

Tags: node.js

I am receiving a warning on an optional dependency, `weak` when i run `yarn install`

I am using `node-gyp@6.0.1` and `node@12.13.0` and `osx 10.14.6`

```
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/lfender/source/ag.js/node_modules/weak: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/lfender/source/ag.js/node_modules/weak
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lfender/source/ag.js/node_modules/weak/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lfender/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/lfender/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/lfender/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/lfender/source/ag.js/node_modules/weak',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/weakref/src/weakref.o
../src/weakref.cc:147:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 3; did you mean 'Nan::Call'?
  globalCallbackDirect->Call(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);
                        ^~~~
                        Nan::Call
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:345:30: note: 'Nan::Call' declared here
inline MaybeLocal<v8::Value> Call(
                             ^
../src/weakref.cc:168:75: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
  Local<Object> proxy = Nan::New<ObjectTemplate>(proxyClass)->NewInstance();
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/lfender/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:6292:3: note: 'NewInstance' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> NewInstance(Local<Context> context);
  ^
/Users/lfender/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:351:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/weakref.cc:223:55: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
  Local<Boolean> rtn = Nan::New<Boolean>(cont->target.IsNearDeath());
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/weakref/src/weakref.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/lfender/source/ag.js/node_modules/weak
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 14.92s.
```

I have trying uninstalling my global `node-gyp` and upgrading to `v6.0.1` but it continues to fail with a message about mismatched arguments. Restarting my system has not helped and I do not want to downgrade node.

The warning began after upgrading node from 11x to 12.13.0

**UPDATE**

this issue also appears to be tracked here https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-weak/issues/99, i will post back once the correct course of action has been determined